# Oracle database TNS The value's length for key 'data source' exceeds it's limit of '128'

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, visual-studio-2012, tnsnames

So I have a connection string to an Oracle Database  essentially I copied it straight from sql developer and then cut out the white space.

I later programmatically add in the user name and password.The problem is that when I try to open an SQLConnection object. I get the error:

```
The value's length for key 'data source' exceeds it's limit of '128'
```

I don't really know much about oracle TNS connections. I used this connection string because it worked in the wizard when I pasted it in and did test connection. And what you see is essentially what Visual studio generated after I pasted in the TNS name.

```
Data Source="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS= (PROTOCOL=TCP)
(HOST=qprd-scan.website.com)(PORT=3726))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=dedicated 
(SERVICE_NAME=DBprd_developer)))";
```

This Data Source key is already around 160 characters.

I was looking at [this post on the MSDN forums.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/fr-FR/e6cac987-1c75-4a32-b030-6812b5fffc5c/the-values-length-for-key-data-source-exceeds-its-limit-of-128?forum=fsharpgeneral)

The guy basically says to chop out some of the other parts out of the data source and put them somewhere else. I am just not really sure how to do that.

[The MSDN on connection strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't really tell me much.

[The MSDN on Connection strings and configuration files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx) didn't help either.

Anyway I would be glad to show more of my code or stuff from app.config if asked

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thank you John, I will be careful of that in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown us the full code you use for connecting to a database, but it seems from a comment to another answer that you are using OLE DB.  I would avoid using it, especially if it seems to have a somewhat arbitrary limit of 128 characters for a data source.

I would also point out that you can also avoid having to install an Oracle client, as recommended by another answerer.  I don't have much experience with the 'instant' client, but the full client is a hefty download and isn't necessary just to be able to connect a C# program to Oracle.

Instead, we can use the Oracle Managed Data Access library.  You can install this using NuGet.  To do this:

- go to Tools > Library Package Manager > Package Manager Console,
- ensure that the correct project is chosen in the 'Default project' drop-down list,
- enter

  ```
  Install-Package odp.net.managed
  ```

This should add download the library from NuGet and add Oracle.ManagedDataAccess to the References of your project.

Then, if you add a `using` directive for `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client`, the following code should talk to an Oracle database:

```
string connStr = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=<hostname>)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=<service_name>)));User Id=<user>;Password=<password>";
Console.WriteLine("Connection string has length " + connStr.Length);
using (var connection = new OracleConnection() { ConnectionString = connStr })
{
    connection.Open();
    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("SELECT * FROM DUAL", connection);
    using (OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks really good. I will test it out for sure, in the mean time, is there a way to read a 2 dimensional array of strings? Actually now I am curious in what format it would return multiple columns of data.

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett: please ask a separate question about the 2-dimensional array of strings.

Comment: I am using the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client, but I still get this problem. I want to avoid using the full oracle client, but this means that the data source definition which would be in the file TnsNames.ora is crammed into the connection string.

Comment: @PhilJollans: if you are using Oracle Managed Data Access and you are still hitting a 128-character limit, please ask a separate question.  Please also include the code you are using to connect to the database, along with the full stacktrace of any exceptions.  It is simply not possible to help you if all I, or anybody else, has to go on is your comment above.

Comment: I agree and I have already done so [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37282108/the-values-length-for-key-data-source-exceeds-its-limit-of-128), Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what my app.config looks like for ODP.NET which I access via customized Enterprise Library (I converted data layer of EnterpriseLibrary5.0 from System.Data.OracleClient to ODP.NET's Oracle.DataAccess.Client. Note that publickey is my own produced one which is unique, and the version is again my own version number). Why did I customize it, well it's because System.Data.OracleClient cannot handle CLOB if it exceeds 32kb.

```
<configSections>
  <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4133a635bb2789db" requirePermission="true" />
</configSections>

<dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="DatabaseConnectionString" />
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DatabaseConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=TestDb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Usrname;Password=Pwd!;Max Pool Size=500;" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />        
</connectionStrings>
```

And my TNS in tnsnames.ora file

```
TestDb=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)
      (HOST=10.10.10.1)
      (PORT=1234)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
      (SID=TestDb)
    )
  )
```

Hope that app.config and tnsnames.ora help you figure it out.

Comment: I have never used a .ora file. Hmm Does it matter where in the solution I put the file?

Comment: You use ora file for oracleclient not in VS solution. It's the connection mapping for your oracle client. product\12.1.0\client_3\Network\Admin\tnsnames.ora

Comment: You have installed [oraclie client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html), right?

Comment: No, I have never used ODP.net. I am just using vanilla visual studio oracle provider for OLE DB.