# The value's length for key 'data source' exceeds it's limit of '128'

Tags: c#, oracle, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, connection-string

I know that a very similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880533/oracle-database-tns-the-values-length-for-key-data-source-exceeds-its-limit), but the answer didn't help me.

I am using Entity Framework 6 with the Oracle.ManagerDataAccess.Client.

If I define the connection string in app.config, then the connection works.
If I specify the identical connection string in code, then I get the error

```
The value's length for key 'data source' exceeds it's limit of '128'.
```

which is correct.

This is my connection string (with some names removed):

```
"User Id=xxxxxxxxxxx;Password=xxxx;Data Source=( DESCRIPTION = ( ADDRESS_LIST = ( ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = VS-ORACLE.xxxxxxx.de)(PORT = 1521) ) ) ( CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = orcl.xxxxxxxx.de) ) )"
```

I know that there are a bunch of spaces which could be removed, but I am still not going to get the string down below 128 characters.

How come it works when the connection string is in app.config, but not when it is in code?

Is there any trick that I can use, by offloading some of the parameters to another string?

I am already using a DBConfiguration object. Is there any way to set some of the parameters in that object?

If I use the full oracle client, I guess that I could reference a configuration in the file tnsnames.ora, but it would be a great bonus if we could talk to an oracle database without the full client.

**Update**

This is what the connection string looks like in app.config

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="OracleDbContext" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="User Id=xxxxxxxxxxx;Password=xxxx;Data Source=( DESCRIPTION = ( ADDRESS_LIST = ( ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = VS-ORACLE.xxxxxxxx.de)(PORT = 1521) ) ) ( CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = orcl.xxxxxxxx.de) ) )" />
</connectionStrings>
```

In code I have defined the context class as follows:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(OracleDBConfiguration))]
public class GlobalAttributeContext : DbContext
{
  public DbSet<GlobalAttribute>  GlobalAttributes { get; set; }

  static GlobalAttributeContext()
  {
    Database.SetInitializer<GlobalAttributeContext>(null);
  }

  public GlobalAttributeContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
  {
  }

  public GlobalAttributeContext() : this ( "Name=OracleDbContext" )
  {
  }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    // We have to pass the schema name into the configuration. (Is there a better way?)
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new GlobalAttribute_Config_Oracle("SchemaName")) ;
  }
}
```

I have defined a DbConfiguration class as follows:

```
class OracleDBConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
  public OracleDBConfiguration()
  {
    this.SetDefaultConnectionFactory ( new System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory("v12.0") ) ;
    this.SetProviderServices ( "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client", Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices.Instance ) ;
    this.SetProviderFactory  ( "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client", Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory.Instance ) ;
  }
}
```

Finally, I create the context like this

```
string ConnectionString = "User Id=xxxxxxxxxxx;Password=xxxx;Data Source=( DESCRIPTION = ( ADDRESS_LIST = ( ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = VS-ORACLE.xxxxxxxx.de)(PORT = 1521) ) ) ( CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = orcl.xxxxxxx.de) ) )" ;

using (var ctx = new GlobalAttributeContext(ConnectionString))
{
  var globalAttributes = ctx.GlobalAttributes.ToList() ;
  foreach ( GlobalAttribute ga in globalAttributes )
  {
    Console.WriteLine ( "Name: {0}, Value: {1}", ga.Attribute, ga.Value ) ;
  }
}
```

The connection strings used in the two methods are identical.

Comment: How are  you setting the connection string in code? I have never seen that error around connection strings before.

Comment: I have added more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My colleague has found an answer to this problem as follows:

Add another constructor to the context class to use an existing connection.

```
public GlobalAttributeContext(DbConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection) 
       : base(existingConnection, true)
{
}
```

This is the complete context class

```
namespace OracleTestExeConfigAndConnStr
{
  [DbConfigurationType(typeof(OracleDBConfiguration))]
  public class GlobalAttributeContext : DbContext
  {
    public DbSet<GlobalAttribute>  GlobalAttributes { get; set; }

    static GlobalAttributeContext()
    {
      Database.SetInitializer<GlobalAttributeContext>(null);
    }

    public GlobalAttributeContext() : base("OracleDbContext")
    {
    }

    public GlobalAttributeContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
           : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
    }

    public GlobalAttributeContext(DbConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection)
           : base(existingConnection, true)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      // We have to pass the schema name into the configuration. (Is there a better way?)
      modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new GlobalAttribute_Config_Oracle("SchemaName")) ;
    }
  }
}
```

Create the database connection as a separate step and pass the connection into the context object.

```
string connStr = @"User Id=xxxxxxxxxxx;Password=xxxx;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=VS-ORACLE.xxxxxxxx.de)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=orcl.xxxxxxxx.de)))";

using (var connection = new OracleConnection() { ConnectionString = connStr })
{
  connection.Open();
  using (var ctx = new GlobalAttributeContext(connection, true))
  {
    var globalAttributes = ctx.GlobalAttributes.ToList();
    foreach (GlobalAttribute ga in globalAttributes)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Value: {1}", ga.Attribute, ga.Value);
    }
  }
}
```

For completeness, this is the DBConfiguration class, which is specified as an attribute on the context class.

```
class OracleDBConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
  public OracleDBConfiguration()
  {
    this.SetDefaultConnectionFactory ( new System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory("v12.0") ) ;
    this.SetProviderServices ( "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client", Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices.Instance ) ;
    this.SetProviderFactory  ( "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client", Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory.Instance ) ;
  }
}
```

This method works from a DLL without requiring any values in app.config.

Answer (score 1):

Once I do not have enough reputation to comment on any question nor answer, I am posting my findings here.

In my case, Phill Jollans' answer almost solved. Below details had to be done additionally

- I did not need that many constructors; only the constructor receiving the connectionstring and passing it to the base class was enough in the context class.
- I had to manually remove the SqlServer connection string provider in app.config file.

Most likely the context was trying to instantiate a connection with SqlServer instead of Oracle, causing that validation to throw this exception.
It seems there is no such limitation for oracle data source key.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any Oracle Client to use the tnsnames.ora file.

Just see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280883/determining-locatation-of-relevant-tnsnames-ora-file/28283924#28283924) (last paragraph) in which folder ODP.NET Managed Driver expects the `tnsnames.ora`, resp. `sqlnet.ora` file.

You can define the alias also in `.config` file, see [Configuring Oracle Data Provider for .NET](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E41125_02/featConfig.htm)

Comment: I want to avoid using the app.config file, because I want to encapsulate the data access in class library which will be used by multiple applications. The database connection is configured and stored independently.

Comment: You don't have to use the app.config file, it is just an option. Specify location of tnsnames.ora file by one of the given possibilities and you are done.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it briefly and failed. I will try again.

Comment: Try environment variable TNS_ADMIN,this should take precedence over all other values

Comment: In the debugger output window I get a lot of messages  Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll  which make me think it is trying to connect to SQL server and not to Oracle. The version with connection string in app.config does specify the provider name, which is missing when I just use the connection string in code. I thought it would come from the DBConfiguration which I have specified as an attribute on the context class.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue somedays ago, the context was trying to instantiate a connection with SqlServer instead of Oracle.

I had to make change on the code below:

```
services.AddDbContext<ManagerContext>(options =>      options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("cnnFinacle")),
                       ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

I Fixed it by changing the UseSqlServer to UseOracle

Mind you this context is on a dotnet core WorkerService